# Is it (width, height) or (height, width)?

Tags: language-agnostic, bitmap, conventions, dimensions

Is there a convention for the order of (height, width) in function arguments or when displaying dimensions?

Comment: i have mostly seen width, height order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know a huge number of languages, but what I have used go with (width, height). It's more fitting along the lines of (x, y) coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say (width, height) is overwhelmingly more common. It never hurts to make it explicit though (through argument naming, etc)

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if there is a convention elsewhere but personally I always use the convention used by graphics (usually even outside of computing, e.g. in photography): width before height.

Answer (score 2):

The (width, height) seems to be more common all around.

Answer (score 1):

it is exactly width-height

Answer (score 1):

In the door and up the stairs. That's the mnemonic I was taught for map co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Display resolution is also normally quoted in "width × height".

[Wikipedia link to Display Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution)